# Nav Bar with Logo in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-frameworks, responsive

I am new to bootstrap . I am developing a responsive page with the help of bootstrap . I am facing issuses with nav bar (position right) with logo (position left).

my issues are:
1. for lower device width toggle button is not working .
2. I am not able to give position to logo and navigation menus in lower decvice.
3. logo is not aliging perfectly on lower device width

please suggest solution of these problems. I have image of issuse no. 2 [image]

Comment: insert your code in http://www.bootply.com/ to see us better

Comment: use this site which helps alot     http://codepen.io/bootstrapped/pen/KwYGwq

Comment: update your question with markup or, better, create live example with issue

Comment: that page is loading . could you please give another link ?

Answer (score 0):

I have attached a link to an example of a navbar with image. Look closely at how it is done ... greetings and welcome!

[EXAMPLE NAVBAR](http://www.bootply.com/f6dapkMdKt#)